Does integration only work for functions?
I argue this because I can't visualize the formula for calculating the center of gravity x component as an integral of a function. It could be defined as: $$\frac{1}{M}\int x dm $$ where $M$ is the total mass of the system and $x$ is the distance from any origin.
However if you imagine what the formula is saying it must be to add up all the tidbits of mass times the distance from some point. Though when I picture this I see two (or more) masses at the same distance from the origin. So some how the function for the masses prints two or more values but that contradicts the definition of a function?
I understand the possible function for mass I'm talking about is actually just $dm$ but maybe could that in the sense I propose be a function and if so by my own logic couldn't be?

$dm$ is referring to some mass measure, i.e., a small mass element. In general, integration is done with respect to a measure - see, for example, stochastic integrals or probability measures.

The ambiguity of two or masses at the same distance from the origin can be resolved by defining the center of mass using proper vector notation. Note that positive and negative distances correspond to different vectors.
$$\vec{x}_{com} = \frac{1}{M} \int \vec{x} dm$$
This can be improved further by redefining mass elements in terms of linear mass density and line elements.
$$\vec{x}_{com} = \frac{1}{M} \int \vec{x} \lambda(\vec{x})dx$$
This definition can be generalized to higher dimensions by using surface mass density and volume mass density together with surface elements and volume elements respectively.
You are right. The notation used in your question conveys its meaning well, but isn't consistent with the mathematical defintion of integration of functions (necessarily single-valued). The integral is actually with respect to position (implicitly), despite the mass element $dm$ written explicitly.
